# Search for notes that only have certain tags in Evernote

Tags: evernote

Is there a way to do a search in Evernote like:

```
only has tag:yr20* or tag:yr21* or tag:mo0* or tag:mo1*
```

or

```
-tag:* tag:yr20* or tag:yr21* or tag:mo0* or tag:mo1*
```

The way I have my Evernote setup is **every** note has a tag that falls into one of these 4 searches:

```
tag:yr20* tag:mo0*

tag:yr20* tag:mo1*

tag:yr21* tag:mo0*

tag:yr21* tag:mo1*
```

So what I'd like to accomplish is if a note has the tags `yr2013` `mo10-Oct` but doesn't have any other tag it would show up in my search.  But if a note has tags `yr2013` `mo10-Oct` `some-other-tag` it would not show up in my search.